# Using data from XML file and placing it in an already made html page

Tags: html, xml, replace

I'm very new to using xml, but I was wondering if there was a way to have an html file, that calls from a separate xml file for information and displays it in the html file.

Basically I already have a specific flyer or product html file, and I want to call the contents of each product( name, description, price, etc) from a separate xml file and generate it in the already made html file.  I see a lot of examples about an xml file generating new html files, but that's not what I need. All i need is for the xml file's information to be displayed on the html, and all the styles on the html file stay effect through css made for that html file.

Can anyone give me some help or point me to the right direction?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go for AJAX

Some Links to get you started:
[Read data from XML and load it through AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp)

PHP has got the support for reading XML Content :
[AJAX-PHP: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp)

http://php.net/xml